# Every point of a grid is colored in blue, red or green. How to prove there is a monochromatic rectangle?

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I have a $3$-coloring of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\{\color{red}{\text{red}},\color{green}{\text{green}},\color{blue}{\text{blue}}\}$.

I have to prove that there is a monochromatic rectangle with its sides being parallel to the axis, i.e. to prove that for some choice of $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$, all the points $(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)\,$ have the same color.

I tried to work by contradiction, without achieving much.

Additionally, can we prove some upper bound on $|a-b|$ and $|c-d|$?

Comment: Every point of _what_ is colored?

Comment: Of a graph... You know the one where all spaces are squares... How do you call them?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking here..... Please can you elaborate?

Comment: [A grid](http://risknfun.com/compform/w1_4.PNG)?

Comment: Every integer coordinate pair? How big is the space we are working in?

Comment: Yes a grid!! So the coordinates would be (0,0) (1,0) (0,1) (1,1)... And it's infinite

Comment: And must the rectangles be aligned with the coordinate axes, or can they be diagonal? For instance, do the points $(-1,0), (0,1),(1,0),(0,-1)$ form a valid rectangle?

Comment: No, they should be aligned.

Comment: Please edit your comments into the body and make a comprehensible question.

Comment: @Jack's edit **makes** this question! Wish I could upvote edits...

Comment: The idea in [Joffan's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1919497/98449) can be used to construct a $4 \times 18$ grid that doesn't have a monochromatic rectangle. And clearly there's such a $3 \times n$ grid for any $n$ (use one colour per row). So what's left is to solve this for grids of size $m \times n$ where $4<m\leq n \leq 18$.

Comment: There is no monochromatic rectangle in an infinite chessboard except for the trivial case of size=1. Considering the answers and the rest of the question I would change "monochromatic rectangle" to "rectangle where the four corner points are monochromatic".

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: I prefer using the terser expression (or even “monochrome rectangle”) and defining one’s terms, as the question as edited by Jack does.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Such a rectangle will occur in a grid of $19$ columns by $4$ rows.

By the pigeonhole principle, each column must have a repeated colour point. Ignoring any later repeats, classify the columns according to the first two repeat colour positions; there are $6$ options: $(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2, 3), (2, 4)$ and $(3,4)$. So since there are also $3$ colour options for the repeated colours there are only $6\times3=18$ different options for repeated colour by position. Therefore, by the pigeonhole principle again, in a $19\times 4$ grid we must have a suitable rectangle with identically coloured corners.

---

From an observation by [Pere](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/354985/pere) in comments:

For $n$ colours, using the same approach, we would adopt a grid of $(n+1)$ rows and then require $n{n+1 \choose 2}+1 = n(n+1)n/2 +1 = (n^3+n^2)/2 + 1$ columns to find a rectangle with same-coloured corners.

Comment: Pigeonhole principle FTW :-).  One of my favorite tools in 'restricted counting' -type problems.

Comment: Is there a general formula for the case of n-colors?

Comment: @Shufflepants Following Joffan's reasoning, for an arbitrary n such a rectangle will occur in a grid of $(n^3+n^2)/2+1$ columns by $n+1$ rows.

Comment: 4 rows is very obviously minimal, and one can also clearly avoid a monochromatic-cornered rectangle by taking the 18 distinct options you mention — but can someone show that _every_ grid with fewer than $19*4=76$ points can be coloured without a m~-c~ r~? Elegantly? (P.S. I am pleased to report this answer currently has $38=19*4/2$ (net) votes up – but I am about to change that!)

Comment: @PJTraill Interesting question. I had a different challenge in mind, whether there is a square 3-coloured grid smaller than $19 \times 19$ that also must have a mono-coloured rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

For a slightly more quantitative proof, we may show that there is a monochromatic rectangle with its largest dimension being $\color{red}{\leq 82}$ and its smallest dimension being $\color{red}{\leq 4}$.

**Step 1.** We may give to any integer point $(x,0)$ on the $x$-axis a maxi-color in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,80,81\}$ depending on the actual colors of $(x,0),(x,1),(x,2),(x,3)$.

**Step 2.** By the Dirichlet box principle, among $82$ consecutive lattice points on the $x$-axis at least two of them, say $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$, have the same maxi-color.

**Step 3.** Since we have only three actual colors, at least two points among $(a,0),(a,1),(a,2),(a,3)$ have the same color. Such points, coupled with the corresponding points on $x=b$, give the wanted monochromatic rectangle.

---

The $82$ above can be replaced by a smaller number, namely $1+\alpha(G)$, i.e. one plus the size of the largest independent set in a quite complicated graph (of the [Haggkvist-Hell](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2199) type) on $81$ vertices. So we may also improve the given bound by using some rather deep results about topological graphs (see [Kneser's conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnesersConjecture.html), proved by Lovasz in 1978 through the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)).

However, an elementary proof that $\alpha(G)=18$ is presented above by Joffan.

Answer (score 4):

Theorem: Let $X,Y$ be infinite sets. If the points of $X\times Y$ are colored with a finite number of colors in such a way that there exists a set $C$ of $c$ colors such that for every $x\in X$ only colors in $C$ appear an infinite number of times among pairs of the form $(x,y)$, then there exist $x_1,x_2\in X,y_1,y_2\in Y$ so that $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ all have the same color.

Proof:

We proceed by induction on $c$, when $c=1$ it is clear. Take any $x_1,x_2$ and let $\alpha$ be the only color that appears an infinite number of times. Notice that the set of $A_{x_1}=\{y\in Y | (x_1,y) \text{ has color }  \alpha\}$ has finite complement, and so does the set $A_{x_2}=\{y\in Y | (x_2,y) \text{ has color }  \alpha\}$. This implies $A_{x_1}\cap A_{x_2}$ is infinite. Taking $x1,x2$ and any $y_1,y_2\in A_{x_1}\cap A_{x_2}$ does the trick.

Inductive step: Consider any $x\in X$, there must be an $\alpha \in Y$ such that the set $A_{x}=\{y\in Y | (x,y) \text{ has color }  \alpha\}$ is infinite. Now consider the set $X'=X\setminus x$ and $Y'=A_x$. If there is an $x'\in X'$ such that there is an infinite number of $y'\in Y'$ such that $(x',y')$ has color $\alpha$ then we are done. just take $x,x'$ and $y_1,y_2$ such that $(x',y_1)$ and $(x',y_2)$ have color $\alpha$. Otherwise notice that the set $C'=C\setminus\alpha$ has $c-1$ elements, and for every $x\in X'$ the only colors that appear an infinite number of times among the pairs $(x,y)$ are in $C'$. By the inductive hypothesis there exist $x_1,x_2\in X'$ and $y_1,y_2\in Y'$ such that $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ all have the same color.

Comment: I think that I'm not quite understanding your language.  Is $C$ the set of finite- or infinite-multiplicity colours?  You seem to say the former, but your base case seems to assume the latter.

Comment: Infinito, let me update

Comment: Definitely a Carl Gauss type of proof :-) i.e. very precise and formal, and equally difficult to connect to the real-world implementation.  Not complaining, just comparing w/ the approach Joffan took.

Comment: Yeah right... I wish this was a Carl Gauss type of proof, thanks @CarlWitthoft

Comment: I'm not convinced.  Let $\alpha=\text{red}$.  Now suppose all the points of the integer lattice with even coordinates receive a unique colour, and the infinitely many other points are coloured red.  The set $A_{x_1}$ is then infinite, yet so is its complement.

Comment: the point is that the set $A_{x_1}$ has finite complement, and so does the set $A_{x_2}$. So the set $A_{x_1}\cap A_{x_2}$ also has finite complement. In particular this implies the set $A_{x_1}\cap A_{x_2}$ is infinite.

Comment: Minor point: I think $\alpha \in Y$ in the first sentence of the inductive step should say $\alpha in C$. Slightly more important, because it requires more effort to work out what it's supposed to say: "*for every $x \in X'$ the only colors that appear an infinite number of times among the pairs $(x,y)$ are in $C'$*" is missing the constraint $y \in Y'$.

Comment: Surely you can greatly simplify the statement by leaving the definition of $C$ and $c$ till the proof? I would also find it a little easier to follow if you defined $C$ as “the set of colours occurring infinitely often in $\{x\}\times Y$ for some $x\in X$”.

Comment: Better: “the set of colours occurring infinitely often in some $\{x\}×Y$ with $x∈X$”

Answer (score 1):

We will decide how to choose rows first. So basically there are three colors so applying the pigeonhole principle if we choose the minimum number of rows to be 4 then it is bound at the worst case one color will repeat.

Now for choosing the minimum number of columns out of 4 rows we will choose any 2 rows and assign its color to be the same, either red blue, or green. This will lead us to the combination of 18 possible options (4C2*3 (for each color)).

So again applying pigeonhole there should be at least 19 (18+1) columns for the possibility of two colors in 4 rows to be the same