# How many colors are needed to color an infinite grid so that no sqaure have the same color in all 4 vertexes?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, coloring

Suppose on a 2 dimension infinite grid, all nodes, or equivalently, all $(p,q)$ points, where $p, q \in \mathbb Z$, need to be painted with a color.

Is there a way that, given enough kinds of paiting colors, e.g. $n$, all sqaures will have at least 2 colors? i.e we can avoid to have any square that all its 4 vertexes are painted in the same color?

Or... is this impossible?

Comment: Do you mean all unit squares or all squares of any size?

Comment: @RossMillikan of any size

Comment: Grid-aligned squares, or are angled squares also allowed (much more complicated)?

Comment: @Joffan I... I was just thinking about some puzzle to amuse myself... and found it's too far beyond my reach. Maybe you can choose either way?

Comment: relevant paper: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/COURSES/250/S15/monosq.pdf

Answer (score 3):

*Solution for rectangles (now removed from question):* In an infinite grid, you require an infinite number of colours. See the closing note in [Every point of a grid is colored in blue, red or green. How to prove there is a monochromatic rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919432/every-point-of-a-grid-is-colored-in-blue-red-or-green-how-to-prove-there-is-a/1919497#1919497) giving the size of a grid required to produce such a rectangle for $n$ colours:

---

> For $n$ colours, using the same approach, we would adopt a grid of $(n+1)$ rows and then require $n{n+1 \choose 2}+1 = n(n+1)n/2 +1 = (n^3+n^2)/2 + 1$ columns to find a rectangle with same-coloured corners.

---

---

**Work on mono squares:**

While the numbers are too big for comfortable imagination, [these notes from Gasarch (link)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/COURSES/250/S15/monosq.pdf) gives a direction to infer the existence of a monochrome grid-aligned square in a sufficiently large 2- or 3-colored grid.

---

One of the key parts of the proof in that paper requires a rather large grid to guarantee the existence of a mono-colored $L$ (three points of the same colour in the form of an $L$: $(x,y),$ $(x+d,y),$ $(x,y+d)$). I wanted to improve on this, at least for two colours and I think the process can apply for more:

Consider the top left to bottom right diagonal of a two-coloured $n\times n$ grid.

If there are three regularly spaced points of the same colour on this diagonal, there is a mono $L$ in the grid. Proof: Consider the points that would form an $L$ with each possible pairing of these three points. If one of these is the relevant colour, that is a mono $L$. If all three are the opposite colour, they form a mono $L$ in that opposite colour.

How long a diagonal do we need to force three regular-spaced points of the same colour? Experimentally the answer is $9$, forced from the following initial patterns (shown red):

$\mathtt {\color{red}{OOXO}OXX?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OOXX}OOX?X}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OXOO}XOXX?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OXOX}XOXO?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OXX}OOXXO?}$

Where in each case the $\mathtt{?}$ creates a regularly-spaced triplet whether filled with $\mathtt{O}$ or $\mathtt{X}$.

Thus any 2-coloured $9\times 9$ grid contains a mono $L$, improving from the above paper's requirement for a $1539\times 1539$ grid for this condition.

To force a mono-$L$ in a three-coloured grid by the same technique you would thus need $10$ regular-spaced points on the diagonal, creating a sparse lower-half grid  of a suitable size to force an $L$ in the remaining two colours. I'm not sure how big this would be but again it should be lower than the corresponding grid size in the paper ($\approx 3^{3^{34}}$).

---

Another observation: the diagonal sequences $\mathtt {OOXOO}$, $\mathtt {OOXXOO}$, or $\mathtt {OXOOXO}$ will also produce a mono $L$ due to the pairs of matched colours at the same spacing. Effectively the three evenly-spaced matching colours is a special case of these where the central point does double duty to left and right. Thus the minimum diagonal length to guarantee a mono $L$ comes down to $8$:

$\mathtt {\color{red}{OOXO}XX?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OOXX}OXO?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OXOO}XX?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OXOX}XOO?}$
$\mathtt {\color{red}{OXX}OO?X}$

---

Some references for solved parts of this problem:
[On Monochromatic Subsets Of A Rectangular Grid](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b82b/d91b596ae3dd3a6ed4cdc2b798276fe09d43.pdf) - a $5{\times} 5$ 2-coloured grid must have a mono $L$.
[Extremal binary matrices without constant
2-squares](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/vdw/2colsq.pdf) - a $15{\times} 14$ 2-coloured grid must have a mono square

Comment: OK, you have changed from rectangles to squares... I will think about this a bit more.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I was thinking about square but somehow typed out a "rectangle".

Comment: @athos no problem... I 'm just thinking about how big a 2-coloured grid is required to force a grid-aligned square to start with.