# Coloring problem

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Let $m$ respectively $n$ parallel lines and consider the $m n$ intersection points which is colored by $2018$ colors. Find the minimum of $m$ and $n$ such that there exists a parallelogram with vertexes of the same colours for any coloring.

Comment: What does "Let m respectively n parallel lines" mean?  It seems like you left something out.  Also in the second part of the sentence, do you mean that each of the intersection points is colored with one of $2018$ colors?

Comment: I guess parallel... So there are $m$ parallel lines, and there is another bunch of $n$ parallel lines not parallel to the first group? Then parallelograms make sense, at lest.

Comment: But then I don't understand why there should be minimal values... Maximum would make more sense, but even then, the problem is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{NOTE}$: This solution is not mine, so please give [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919432/every-point-of-a-grid-is-colored-in-blue-red-or-green-how-to-prove-there-is-a) credit for this solution.

Let's first consider the case of 3 colors. What is the minimum $m,n$ to guaranteed a monochromatic parallelogram?

Such a parallelogram will occur in a grid of 19 columns ($m$) by 4 rows ($n$).

By the pigeonhole principle, each column must have a repeated colour point. Ignoring any later repeats, classify the columns according to the first two repeat colour positions; there are 6 options: (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4) and (3,4). So since there are also 3 colour options for the repeated colours there are only 6×3=18 different options for repeated colour by position. Therefore, by the pigeonhole principle again, in a 19×4 grid we must have a suitable parallelogram with identically coloured corners.

For $n$ colors, using the same approach, we would adopt a grid of $(n+1)$ rows and then require $n{n+1 \choose 2}+1 = n(n+1)n/2 +1 = (n^3+n^2)/2 + 1$ columns to find a parallelogram with same-coloured corners.